# Moving empty values of an array to the last position

Tags: php, arrays, api

I'm pulling an array from an external API, And I've got some help with **usort** on here, And It pushes it to the bottom, and empty values are on top. I tried using **unset** but that just emptied out my entire **realArrival** values.

e.g.

```
  $fromThis = array(
      "realArrival": "",
      "realArrival": "Confirm. 06:18",
      "realArrival": "Confirm. 06:19"
  );
```

Into:

```
  $intoThis = array(
      "realArrival": "Confirm. 06:18",
      "realArrival": "Confirm. 06:19",
      "realArrival": ""
  );
```

Here is my code on how I tried to do it. I'm sure you are shaking your head at this but here it goes.

```
        $url = 'http://apis.is/flight?language=en&type=arrivals';
        $json = file_get_contents($url);
        $results = json_decode($json, TRUE);
        $results = $results['results'];

        function cmp($a, $b) {
            return strcmp($a['realArrival'], $b['realArrival']);
        }

        //Sort Time   
        usort($results, "compare_time");
        function compare_time($a,$b) {
            $splitA= count(explode(' ',$a['realArrival']));
            $splitB= count(explode(' ',$a['realArrival']));
            if($splitA==2 && $splitB==2)
            {
                $first_time = strtotime(explode(' ',$a['realArrival'])[1]);
                $second_time = strtotime(explode(' ',$b['realArrival'])[1]);
                if($first_time==$second_time)
                {
                    return strcmp($b['realArrival'], $a['realArrival']);
                }
                return ($second_time < $first_time)  ? 1: 0;
            }
            return strcmp($a['realArrival'], $b['realArrival']);
        }

        echo '<table class="highlight bordered responsive-table grey darken-2 col s6">';
            echo "<tr>";
                echo '<th>Date</th>';
                echo '<th>Flight Number</th>';
                echo '<th>Airline</th>';
                echo '<th>From</th>';
                echo '<th>Schedule. Time</th>';
                echo '<th>Status</th>';
            echo "</tr>";
        foreach ($results as $item => $val) {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo '<td>'.$val['date'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$val['flightNumber'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$val['airline'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$val['from'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$val['plannedArrival'].'</td>';
                // HERE I TRIED TO TARGET THE EMPTY VALUES
                if ($val === "") {
                    unset($results[$item]);
                    $results[] = $val;
                    echo '<td style="font-weight: bold;">'.$val['realArrival'].'</td>';
                }

            echo '</tr>';
        }
```

Comment: Invalid given array. That would return `unexpected ':'`

Answer (score 0):

I know this might seem clunky, but you could always just do something like...

```
$items_with_real_arrivals = array();
$items_without_real_arrivals = array();

foreach ($results as $item => $val) {
    if ($item[‘realArrival’] === "") { $items_without_real_arrivals.push($item); }
    else $items_with_real_arrivals.push($item);
}

$reordered_items = array();
for ($i=0; $i<count($items_with_real_arrivals); $i++) {
    $reordered_items.push($item);
}
for ($i=0; $i<count($items_without_real_arrivals); $i++) {
    $reordered_items.push($item);
}

foreach ($reordered_items as $item => $val) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '    <td>'.$val['date'].'</td>';
    echo '    <td>'.$val['flightNumber'].'</td>';
    echo '    <td>'.$val['airline'].'</td>';
    echo '    <td>'.$val['from'].'</td>';
    echo '    <td>'.$val['plannedArrival'].'</td>';
    echo '    <td style="font-weight:bold;">' . $val['realArrival'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: I think I get this. This does although return an empty array.

Comment: @Hokus_Pokus I wasn’t sure exactly what the structure of $results looks like—maybe taking the for loop one dimension deeper would work(?). More or less, though, I thought maybe the concept might help.

Comment: Also this would probably not be the most resource-efficient way if you’re pulling in big amounts of data in $results. It’s clunky but if you tinker with the concept it should work.